# SCNNode will not release affter collision

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

I added two SCNNode to the scene to let them collide. The SCNNode is removed after the collision is over, but the removed SCNNode is not released. Dealloc will not be called.

Comment: You can reuse them smartly

Comment: Are you using closures? Within a closure you can retain a strong reference without even realizing it. Can you please share your code?